# Common SQL query in Zend-Framework

Tags: php, sql, model-view-controller, zend-framework, zend-framework2

How i can use a sql-query code that i already have on Zend-Framework using Model and Controller?

I'm tried of many ways and i can't solve this.

This is a example of "common sql-query code" to test:
**"SELECT id_arquivos_retorno FROM sa_arquivos_retorno LIMIT 100"**

*My original code it's a big query and it's terrible transform to a zend-select()

This is my Model:

```
class PedidosInscricoesModel extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract{

protected $_name = 'sa_arquivos_retorno';

public function getPedidosInscricoes(array $params) {

$this->_db = Zend_Registry::get('db2');

$session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('autenticacao');

    $query =    $this->query("SELECT id_arquivos_retorno FROM sa_arquivos_retorno LIMIT 100");

    $retorno = $this->fetchAll($query)->toArray();

    return $retorno;
}}
```

And That's my Controller:

```
public function indexAction()
{        
    $PedidosInscricoesModel = new PedidosInscricoesModel();

    $this->view->id_arquivos_retorno = $_REQUEST['id_arquivos_retorno'];

    $params = $this->_request->getParams();
    $data = $PedidosInscricoesModel->getPedidosInscricoes($params);

    $this->view->data = $retorno;
}
```

My index view:

```
<?php
    foreach($this->data as $dados) {
?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $dados["id_arquivos_retorno"]; ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
```

-Sorry for bad english guys

Answer (score 0):

I got it!
Just modifying the *Model* using "**zend_db_statement**" in this way:

```
class PedidosInscricoesModel extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract{

public function getPedidosInscricoes()
{

    $db = Zend_Registry::get('db2');

    $sql = "SELECT id_arquivos_retorno FROM sa_arquivos_retorno LIMIT 20";

    $stmt = $db->query($sql);

    $retorno = $stmt->fetchAll();

    return $retorno;
}
}
```